# Why does Plunker give 404 errors with AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-router, plunker

This code works fine when I run it locally but when I put it in this Plunker (http://plnkr.co/edit/RCMbxv7Peb83tRKWTMJM) I get the following looping 404 errors:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://run.plnkr.co/main.html
GET http://run.plnkr.co/main.html 404 (Not Found) angular.js:8521
```

What am I missing?

Comment: If you turn off HTML5 mode it works fine

Comment: @Asok Yes, thank you that fixes it and since I'm not caring about html 5 mode at this time that fixes my issue. If you'd like to add that as and answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you turn off HTML5 mode it will work fine.

Your app.js file:

```
// html5Mode is default to false so you could comment out or manually set it
//$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

`html5Mode` requires server side configuration so I believe that is the conflict.

Answer (score 4):

The accepted answer is only partially correct.

In general, url routing will work on Plunker exactly as it would work if your code were hosted in a **sub directory** (ie: not the root). This is important if you are using `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true)` as it may lead to unexpected behaviour if you want to use absolute urls (eg: `/partials/template.html`).

If you use one of the built-in Angular.js templates, you will notice that I have added a bit of a hack to get around the fact that previews are not hosted on subdomains:

```
<script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
```

This takes advantage of how Angular.js' `$locationProvider` treats `<base href="">` tags by injecting a dynamic base tag before Angular.js bootstraps. See the *relative links* section on: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location

Answer (score 0):

Experienced the same issue. I changed the version of my added angular script to 
data-semver="1.3.0-beta.5" and it is sorted.